# Livecode Block Tab Key

Tags: livecode

How do we block the tab key?

`//this handler is not executed on simulator, maybe because it is supported only in Desktop and Web?`

`on tabKey`

`end tabKey`

What I want is, when a user pressed `tab` key, it should not add any space. Pressing tab in development does not add add space but when I ran it in iPad simulator 8.2, it adds space when tab is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rawKeyDown` message should do what you want.

```
on rawKeyDown theKey
  if theKey is not 65509 then
    pass rawKeyDown
  end if
end rawKeyDown
```

Comment: Does 65509 works only on real ios device? I tried alerting the `theKey` in simulator and press tab key in the keyboard, it is `0`.

Comment: According to the docs, it works. You can also try the `keyDown` message and check for `tab`.

Comment: If it doesn't work and you're not using a native field, you may want to report it as a bug.